# Stream a value from firebase phone login in flutter bloc/cubit dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm testing firebase phone authentication in my flutter app to see how well it performs, by the way I'm new to dart and flutter. So I started to use the flutter bloc for more grain control of my app.

```
**bool codeSent = false;**

Future<void> verifyPhoneNo(String mobileno, Duration duration) async {
try {
  final auth.PhoneVerificationCompleted phoneVerificationCompleted =
      (auth.AuthCredential authResult) async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authResult);
  };
  final auth.PhoneVerificationFailed phoneVerificationFailed =
      (auth.FirebaseAuthException authException) {
    print(authException.message);
    throw LogInWithOTPFailure();
  };
  final auth.PhoneCodeSent phoneCodeSent =
      (String verId, [int forceResend]) {
    **this.codeSent = true;**
    print("authRepo" + codeSent.toString() + " " + verId);
    this.verificationId = verId;
  };
  final auth.PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
      (String verId) {
    this.verificationId = verId;
    throw LogInWithOTPTimeOut();
  };
  _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: mobileno,
      timeout: duration,
      verificationCompleted: phoneVerificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: phoneVerificationFailed,
      codeSent: phoneCodeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
} catch (_) {
  print(_);
  throw LogInWithOTPFailure();
}
```

Above code is inside AuthRepository and I just want to listen the codesent triggred or not!
I tried to use the stream and no way of getting the that codesent boolean value out of the repository.

If I get that value and I can emit those value(s) in my view bloc listener through cubit, It will be very helpful.

Is there anyway I can stream those values especially codeSent?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am currently looking for a solution to the same problem. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Still no way.. I had to look for other resources.